# Bad Request Piwik

Tags: bad-request, matomo

I get this error when I try to call a PIWIK API.

```
Bad Request

Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.
Size of a request header field exceeds server limit.
Cookie: piwik_visitor2=1%3DMjQ2NzVkZWQzNWE2NmVmZTg0MDAzYjcxNDVjMWNkYjM%3D%3A2%3....
```

How can I get ride of this. Piwik is hosted on one of our server. Is there anything to do with Apache config?

By the way, it has been working for quite a while. But it has suddenly stopped working.

Please advise.

Thanks,
Imran

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug in Piwik, that will be fixed at some point in the future: http://dev.piwik.org/trac/ticket/409

However as per info in the ticket, the team will release a fix to stop causing the error for 1.0, in next weeks probably.

Comment: Thanks Pascal.

Is there any quick workaround to fix this problem?

Comment: would you mind marking as resolved, as the bug and the question are now answered/resolved ;)